# create a new data frame from GroupBy object in pandas

Tags: sql, pandas

What I really want to do can be expressed in `sql` like this:

`SELECT v1, v2, COUNT(*) AS v_count FROM my_table GROUP BY 1,2`

that means, I want to create a new data frame which is composed of 3 columns: `(v1, v2, v_count)`.

Here is what I tried with `pandas`:

```
grp = df.groupby(['v1', 'v2'])  # GROUP BY v1, v2
cnt = grp.count()  # get v_count for each group
```

but how to put them together into a new data frame?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can select one of the aggregated columns to be `v_count` and then reset the index since `v1` and `v2` are in the index, e.g.:

```
df.groupby(['v1', 'v2'])['v1'].agg({'v_count': np.size}).reset_index()
```

Alternatively, you can use the `as_index` keyword argument instead of using `reset_index`, e.g.:

```
df.groupby(['v1', 'v2'], as_index=False)['v1'].agg({'v_count': np.size})
```