# Creating a Pandas Data Frame from groupby

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following groupby statement;

```
test1_df = pd.DataFrame(cust_merge_df.groupby(['customer_org', 'reseller']).size())
```

Which returns the following:

```
print(test1_df)
                                                                    0
customer_org                     reseller                           
cust1                            reseller 1                       26
cust2                            reseller 2                        1
cust3                            reseller 3                       14
```

What I need to be able to do is split the data into 3 columns where **customer_org** and **reseller** are the column headers;

```
customer_org                     reseller                        total  
cust1                            reseller 1                       26
cust2                            reseller 2                        1
cust3                            reseller 3                       14
```

I tested the suggestions @ [create a new data frame from GroupBy object in pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24572376/create-a-new-data-frame-from-groupby-object-in-pandas) without success.

Comment: `cust_merge_df.groupby(['customer_org', 'reseller']).size().to_frame('total').reset_index()` or `cust_merge_df.groupby(['customer_org', 'reseller'], as_index=False).size().to_frame('total')` ?

Comment: Try `cust_merge_df.groupby(['customer_org', 'reseller']).size().reset_index(name='total')`

Comment: @JohnGalt, That did it! Thanks!